# R uploads numeric value into boolean column - why?

Tags: r, boolean

I want to upload an Excel file as a dataframe in R.
It is a large file with a lot of numbers and some #NV values.

The upload works good for the majority of columns (in total, there are 4,000 columns). But for some columns, R changes the columns to "TRUE" or "FALSE", creating a boolean column.

I don't want that, since all of the columns are supposed to be numeric.

Do you know why R does that?

Answer (score 0):

**It would really help if you provided code snippets, because there are many different excel-to-dataframe libraries/methods/behaviors.**

But assuming that you are using `writexl`, the [`read_excel`](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html) function has a `guess_max` parameter for this kind of case. `guess_max` is 1000 by default.

Try `df <- read_excel(path = filepath, sheet = sheet_name, guess_max = 100000)`

Since dataframes cannot have different data types in the same column, `read_excel` has to read your excel file and guess what data type each column should be, before actually filling the dataframe. If a column happens to only have NA values in the first 1000 rows, `read_excel` will assume you have a column of booleans, and then all subsequent values encountered in future rows will be cast accordingly. So if you set `guess_max` to something huge, you make `read_excel` slower, but it might avoid the casting of numerics to booleans.